# The keyboard covers the input field

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-webview

The application must support full-screen mode, that is, so that the content completely fills the screen and the status bar and the bottom navigation bar are not visible.
Here is the code for how I reached this solution:

Manifest fragments:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Game"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:targetApi="31">

        <activity
            android:name=".activity.BrowserActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:resizeableActivity="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:screenOrientation="sensor">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Theme:

```
<style name="Theme.Game" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:targetApi="q">false</item>

        <item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">shortEdges</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>

        !-- Fullscreen related items -->
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="21">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
```

Fragments BrowserActivity:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().hide();
        }

        getWindow().setFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        );

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
            );
        }
```

Everything works fine, but any input field is completely or partially covered by the keyboard. That is, there is no scrolling of the input field.
When I remove from the topic:

```
<item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">shortEdges</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

Everything works, but the status bar is just a dark bar and the content does not fill the entire screen area.

What is the problem?